# Hibernate Query Returning only one value

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a Spring Hibernate App and I am accessing a table that has the following values:

```
select REPAIR_STATUS_CD,STATUS_DATE 
from repair_status 
where REPAIR_CONF_NO ='1234567';

REPAIR_STATUS_CD STATUS_DATE          
----- -------------------- - 
NEWO  25-FEB-2016 20:07:45 
RLSD  25-FEB-2016 20:07:45 
REQA  25-FEB-2016 20:13:24 
URCD  26-FEB-2016 19:43:40 
UINS  26-FEB-2016 19:43:45 
UBER  27-FEB-2016 09:42:59 
RQT6  27-FEB-2016 09:46:28 
RQXP  03-MAR-2016 12:24:43 
RBER  04-MAR-2016 21:52:22 
SPCM  09-MAY-2016 18:13:33 
SCOM  10-MAY-2016 19:09:54
```

Now in the DAOImpl Class I am fetching the same using the below code.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            session.beginTransaction();

            Query<RepairStatus> query = session.createQuery("from     RepairStatus where repairConfNo = '"+repairConfNo+"' ");
            List<RepairStatus> repairStatusList = query.getResultList();    
            System.out.println("Inside Repair Status Service");
            for(RepairStatus repairStatus: repairStatusList){
                System.out.println(repairStatus.getRepairStatusCode());
            }
```

But when I print the output using the sysout and the for loop I am getting the following:

Inside Repair Status Service

```
NEWO
NEWO
NEWO
NEWO
NEWO
NEWO
NEWO
NEWO
NEWO
```

Why are the rows getting repeated although the database has proper values.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Also this is my Entity Class

```
package com.gsx.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TG_REPAIR_STATUS")
public class RepairStatus {

@Id
@Column(name="REPAIR_CONF_NO")
private String repairConfNo;

@Column(name="REPAIR_STATUS_CD")
private String repairStatusCode;

@Column(name="STATUS_DATE")
private Date statusDate;

public void setStatusDate(Date statusDate) {
    this.statusDate = statusDate;
}

public String getRepairConfNo() {
    return repairConfNo;
}

public void setRepairConfNo(String repairConfNo) {
    this.repairConfNo = repairConfNo;
}

public Date getStatusDate() {
    return statusDate;
}

public String getRepairStatusCode() {
    return repairStatusCode;
}

public void setRepairStatusCode(String repairStatusCode) {
    this.repairStatusCode = repairStatusCode;
}

}
```

Comment: The code has SQL injection but actually is fine.

Comment: @StanislavL Thanks a lot for the quick response. But I did not get what is incorrect here :) Sorry

Comment: enable "show sql" and see what the sql query looks like

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
Query<RepairStatus> query = session.createQuery("from     RepairStatus where repairConfNo = '"+repairConfNo+"' ");
```

to

```
Query<RepairStatus> query = session.createQuery("from     RepairStatus where repairConfNo =:repairConfNo");
parameterQuery.setParameter("repairConfNo", you_repairConfNo);
List<RepairStatus> repairStatusList = query.getResultList();
```

Query is look good, you need to enable the `show_sql`

if your are using `hibernate.cfg.xml`then you can enable the sql like

> ```
> <property name="show_sql">true</property>
> ```

then debug the generated sql by hibernate, it can help you to find out the issue.

Also your table name is **TG_REPAIR_STATUS**

```
@Table(name="TG_REPAIR_STATUS")
public class RepairStatus
```

and you are running query

```
select REPAIR_STATUS_CD,STATUS_DATE 
from repair_status 
where REPAIR_CONF_NO ='1234567';
```

on **repair_status**  table instead of **TG_REPAIR_STATUS**  table, please verify this on your database

Comment: Tried using show_sql as True and got the following:                    Hibernate: select repairstat0_.REPAIR_CONF_NO as REPAIR_CONF_NO1_0_, repairstat0_.REPAIR_STATUS_CD as REPAIR_STATUS_CD2_0_, repairstat0_.STATUS_DATE as STATUS_DATE3_0_ from TG_REPAIR_STATUS repairstat0_ where repairstat0_.REPAIR_CONF_NO='276139092'........The table name is TG_REPAIR_STATUS and the mappings are correct..it was just a typo. :) But this does not seem to be solving the issue

Comment: can you please run `select REPAIR_STATUS_CD,STATUS_DATE 
from TG_REPAIR_STATUS 
where REPAIR_CONF_NO ='276139092'`
in you database and past the output here?

Comment: select REPAIR_STATUS_CD,STATUS_DATE from TG_REPAIR_STATUS where REPAIR_CONF_NO ='276139092';

    REPAI STATUS_DATE
    ----- --------------------
    NEWO  14-APR-2017 07:32:00
    REQA  14-APR-2017 08:32:36
    RLSD  14-APR-2017 07:32:00
    RQT6  18-APR-2017 05:35:19
    RQXP  21-APR-2017 07:39:32
    UINS  17-APR-2017 15:00:31  
    URCD  17-APR-2017 14:59:39
    URTN  18-APR-2017 05:34:41
    USHP  28-APR-2017 06:13:31

    9 rows selected.

Comment: pretty strange, can you share you code if it's on git ?